# Selenium WebDriver Not Detecting Follower Count Element on Certain Twitter Profiles

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a Selenium script to scrape the follower counts of accounts. It's working for most accounts, however, for a few of them, I get the "Element not found" exception. Really not sure why. I compared the Xpaths of the accounts that gave this error to the errors and found them to be different (which is strange, given the follower count element on twitter should have the same xpath on all profiles), but even after changing the xpath expression, the error persisted.

I'm really confused as to why this is happening. It seems like for a few Twitter profiles, none of the elements on the page is interactable. I need some help figuring out why. This is a snippet of the code:

```
url = f"https://twitter.com/{acc}"
service = ChromeService()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
f = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/a[1]/span[1]/span[1]").text
print(f)
```

Tried to scrape twitter follower counts. Failed to do so for a few particular accounts because element not found.

Comment: you can check for that specific page there must be css that is getting change.so you need to find that selector that can match every case!

Comment: I did see that the xpath is getting changed, but even when I use the changed xpath expression for those accounts the elements aren't getting detected!